# undefined method `charset=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From this method in my mailer : `mail(to: params[:email], subject: "Hello World")`.
I try to send an email but I get this error: `undefined method 'charset=' for nil:NilClass`
The view of the mail :

```
#newsletter.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

I use rails 5.2.2.

EDIT: controller :

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def inscription_newsletter
        SendInBlueMailer.with(email: params[:mailer][:email]).newsletter.deliver_later
    end

end
```

mailer :

```
class SendInBlueMailer < ApplicationMailer

    def newsletter
      mail(to: params[:email], subject: "Hello World")
    end

end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Will setting `body` in your `mail` method correct this?

Comment: Also, what is the file name of your mailer template?

Comment: Although there is a `charset=` in your template, the error is most likely unrelated to your HTML content. Check the error's stack trace for file names and line numbers – it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: As I get this error I would like to know what should I do to get it work? And I tried everything but it still not working...

Comment: @Stefan is correct. To get better answers, please post more details. A more full stacktrace is a good place to start.

Comment: @Airvanne the meta tag isn't required...if you remove that line, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, I have the same error.. in the controller I put deliver_later (instead of deliver_now) I have this as an error: `[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::Parameterized::DeliveryJob] [3e6e0889-82db-4e33-9ae1-51f4bf86232d] Error performing ActionMailer::Parameterized::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 3e6e0889-82db-4e33-9ae1-51f4bf86232d) from Async(mailers) in 8.1ms: NoMethodError (undefined method `charset=' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: follow this guide to improve your abilities to debug your rails app http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Maybe you need Doublequotes (") instead of Singlequotes (') in your newsletter.html.erb

Comment: If you are using `HTML5`, the `charset` attribute can be written separately. Like this: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, there are some difference on syntax between different HTML versions. Check [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) (**Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5**) and try to change the syntax, see if this can fix the problem : )

Comment: I had same issue. Error raised from action_mailer/base.rb#mail method. Solution was remove old mailer and create new mailer without using Mailer in generator name. like `rails g mailer SendInBlue newsletter`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by adding to the `initialize` method `super`.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    layout 'mailer'

    def initialize
        @send_in_blue = SibApiV3Sdk::SMTPApi.new
        super
    end
end
```